# Why does adding a speed to toggle affect ':visible'?

Tags: jquery

I am working on some functionality to show a div containing some text when a user clicks on a link.

The link initially displays the text 'show +' and then when the div is revealed this text changes to 'hide -'.  Code is below:

**JQUERY**

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('p.link + div').hide();
    $('p.link a').prepend('<span>info +</span> ');

    $('p.link a').click(function(e) {
     var vis = $(this).parent().next().toggle().is(':visible');
     $(this).find('span').text(vis ? 'hide -' : 'info +');
     e.preventDefault();
    });
    });
    </script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <p class="link"><a href="#" class="show-hide"> </a></p>

    <div class="info">

    <p>Some sample text to show and hide</p>

    </div> <!-- info -->
```

This is all working fine but then I decided rather then an immediate show / hide, it would be nice to gradually reveal the text by adding a speed to the toggle.  I therefore amended the following line:

**JQUERY**

```
    var vis = $(this).parent().next().toggle("slow").is(':visible');
```

This gives me the transition effect I want but now the link text is not changing.  It still initially displays as 'info +' but from there on after, regardless of whether or not the div is displayed or not, the link text reads 'hide -'.

I assume this is because somehow the code is always seeing the div as being displayed even when it is not but I am unsure of how to fix this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the callback argument of `toggle` to execute your statement after the transition is done, rather than trying to execute it immediately after.

```
var span = $(this).find('span');
$(this).parent().next().toggle("slow", function() {
  span.text($(this).is(":visible") ? 'hide -' : 'info +');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cY7zM/)

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly.  Just been reading about callbacks and it makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straightforward why it's happening. If you do the check straight after you fade, it goes like this: fading an element in means it's not hidden, which means it's visible; Fading an element out means it's not hidden, which means it's visible.

You could store the state first:

```
var elem = $(this).parent().next();
var vis = elem.is(':visible');
elem.toggle("slow");
```

Or, store the state in a class (which would work better if the user was to click successively)

```
var vis = $(this).parent().next().toggleClass("visible").toggle("slow").hasClass("visible");
```